# Why do we still use permittivity of free space in gauss law even if we are in matter?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrostatics, magnetic-fields, gauss-law

In the derivation of the electric field inside a non conducting sphere, We still use the permittivity of free space even though we are in a medium.

The same applies for ampere's law in a solid wire.

http://physics.bu.edu/~duffy/semester2/c15_inside.html

https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/athena/course/8/8.02-esg/Spring03/www/8.02ch24we.pdf

Comment: It's a fundamental law, it's always true whether you're in a medium or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will [note in this table](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/permeability-d_1923.html) that the relative permeability of non-ferromagnetic materials is very close to one.
For example:
Air 1.00000037
Copper 0.999994

Then [as this table shows](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/relative-permittivity-d_1660.html) for a lot of gases the relative permittivity is also close to one eg air 1.000536, argon 1.000513. 
However if the material can be polarised then one would have to multiply the permittivity of free space by the relative permittivity eg Sulphur 3.5, Marble 8

Comment: So for non conducting material, the assumption is based on that Er = 1?

Comment: @user3733086 A good example is the parallel plate capacitor. If there is air between the plates then $\epsilon_0$ is used but if there is sulphur between the plates then one needs to use $\epsilon_{\rm sulphur}$.

Comment: It is true that we are living in a medium, but using permittivity of free space as a reference point helps to write up formula; instead of writing many equations, we can write one equation with an empirical coefficient: dielectric constant.